# M2 typeM PCB design interference

Tags: pcb-design, m2

I found online an M2 keyE to M2 keyM adaptor design done with KiCAD:
https://github.com/CRImier/MyKiCad/tree/master/Laptop%20mods/nvme_ae_to_m

One thing I can't understand: in readme he states

> FOXCONN AS0BC21-S20BM-7H socket datasheet was used for reference

I googled for it, and found the PCB layout guideline for this Foxconn connector:

[image]

From this layout, it seems obvious (to me) that:

- Pin1 is right next to the big pad on top left,
- M2 SSD shall be inserted into from bottom of this drawing (see the locker hole's position)

However, in the above github design:

[image]

Entry side here is also drawn to the bottom, but look at the "non-pin" sections of the socket! It seems mirrored to me.

Could you verify this for me? Is this design works "only-by-luck"? Pin numbers seems valid:

[image]

But this connector desing seems having extra pins (pins 12..20) and also some missing ones (35,37,59..66).

### Details for extra pins (12..20) ([pinout source](https://pinoutguide.com/HD/M.2_NGFF_connector_pinout.shtml))

[image]

This board has only one PCIe lane, so it skips all other PCIe lanes. PCB:

[image]

So wiring seems OK for these extra pins, although I don't understand why Foxconn skips these on their datasheet.

### Details for missing pins (35,37,59..66)

[image]
[image]

So 35 and 37 is skipped safely as it's PCIe, and 59..66 seems skipped due to pinout specification for being the "M" notch.

But then why Foxconn's datasheet contains connectors for 59..66, and not for 12..20?

It really seems either Foxconn's datasheet is wrong or pinout guide is wrong, or the above github repository's design is wrong and I can't decide:

If both Foxconn's datasheet and pinout guide is correct, then designs based on this datasheet misses both PCIe lane2 and lane3 ruining SSD's transfer speeds.

Can you please help me out understanding what's going on here?